# A generator which is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, algebraic-curves

Let $F\subset L$ be a field extension, and $x,\alpha,\beta\in L$.

My question is:

Assume that $F(\alpha)\subset L$ is an algebraic extension.
If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(\beta)$, then is $x$ algebraic over $F(\beta)$?

Thank you.

Comment: This was confusing to parse. You can just assume that $\beta \in F$ WLOG by replacing $F$ with $F(\beta)$ if necessary, so the question is: if $x$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$, and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then is $x$ algebraic over $F$? The answer is yes (just think about the degrees in the tower $F \to F(\alpha) \to F(\alpha, x)$).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
But, I did not assume that $\beta$ is not necessarily in $F$. So, my question is:
If $x\in L$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$, and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(\beta)$, then is $x$ algebraic over $F(\beta)$?

In this setting, there are two towers:
$F\to F(\alpha)\to L$ and $F\to F(\beta)\to L$.

Comment: @sola The point Qiaochu was making is that it makes no difference assuming that $\beta\in F$. His comment still works without doing this too: you know that $[F(\alpha,\beta,x):F]\geq [F(x):F]$, and you know that all extensions in the tower $F\to F(\alpha)\to F(\alpha,\beta)\to F(\alpha,\beta,x)$ are finite by algebraicity.